Looking for a (possibly) webcomic strip. A torch girl lights up the torch of a friend at his request before questioning the necessity of doing so
I stumbled on this comic strip randomly online some time ago while browsing the Internet, between 2020 and 2023, although I cannot say for sure how old it can possibly be. And just in case, this was before the movie "Elemental" was advertised.
Although I'm calling it a webcomic, I'm unsure if it was part of a bigger story or if it was just that one strip.
The strip contained 3 or 4 panels and the art looked simple and innocent (flat colour, very geometric faces, instead of something complicated/realistic like DC Comics, Marvel or mangas and such).

In the 1st panel, you could see 2 characters seemingly walking inside some sort of cave, a guy who looked blue and a girl who looked orange/red (maybe she looked like a flame too). The guy pulled out a torch and asked if the girl could like it up for him.
In the second panel, the girl used her power to light up the torch, to which the guy replied: "Thanks!"
In the third panel, the girl told the guy something in the line of: "You know I'm a living torch, right?", as if questioning the necessity of lighting up a torch when she's already illuminating their surroundings by being there.
I'm unsure if this panel exists or if it's just my imagination from trying to remember it, but I think the fourth panel was a close-up on the guy's smiling face, as if it was a poker face reaction to what she just said.

